# Database objects change during debugging

Tags: c#, database, debugging, asp.net-core

I am writing a project called Social Network. It's ASP.NET Core Web Application + template Web Application (Model-View-Controller). I wrote the ability to add friends, but it does not work.

After adding a friend, I want to display a page with his data, but it appears that he has no friends.

But friends will be displayed if you do the following (User has no friends. I entered the database. Friends have appeared. How?):

[image: Screenshots]

User Model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Sex { get; set; }

    public List<UserModel> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SocialNetwork.Models;

namespace SocialNetwork.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        SocialNetworkContext db;
        public HomeController(SocialNetworkContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var user = db.Users.First(u => u.Name == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            return Redirect($"~/Home/UserProfile/{user.Id}");
        }

        public IActionResult UserProfile(int Id)
        {
            ViewBag.is_auth_user = IsAuthorizedUser(Id);
            var user = db.Users.First(u => u.Id == Id);
            return View(user);
        }

        public IActionResult AddFriend(int Id)
        {
            var user = db.Users.First(u => u.Name == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            var new_friend = db.Users.First(u => u.Id == Id);
            if (user.Friends == null)
            {
                user.Friends = new List<UserModel>();
            }
            user.Friends.Add(new_friend);
            db.Users.Update(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect($"~/Home/UserProfile/{new_friend.Id}");
        }

        public IActionResult Users()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int Id)
        {
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
            return View(user);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(UserModel user)
        {
            db.Users.Update(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect($"~/Home/UserProfile/{user.Id}");
        }

        protected bool IsAuthorizedUser(int Id)
        {
            var user = db.Users.First(u => u.Name == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            if (user.Id == Id)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how this is possible.

Comment: Could you please show us how the error looks like ?

Comment: This looks like a lazy loading issue in EF. Basically, the entities aren't loaded until you access them. Try using `Include("Friends")` when loading the user in the `UserProfile()` method. This will ensure that the related entities are always loaded.

Comment: Did i got you wrong? `return Redirect($"~/Home/UserProfile/{new_friend.Id}");` so you are redirecting to the (new) user profile of your just added friend ... does this friend have `Friends`? Or is your problem, that after navigation to `"~/Home/UserProfile/{user.Id}"`, your just added friend does not appear?

Comment: @nilsK No. So it was intended. Yes. I do not see friends after adding.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane Yes!) It works)) Thank you very much. I spent a lot of time to understand what is wrong. You can write the answer so that I mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a lazy loading issue in EF.

Basically, the entities aren't loaded until you access them.

Try using `Include("Friends")` when loading the user in the `UserProfile()` method.

This will ensure that the related entities are always loaded.